# Admin Filter - Add Post Type Description on Post Type Page

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, description

WordPress allows adding `descriptions` to Custom Post Types whenever it's registered. ( [`register_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type). I would like to output that title on the Admin Landing Page ( View All *Post Type* ) preferably underneath the title. I've looked into `/wp-admin/edit.php` but I'm not sure if the filter presented is usable in this case ( and thus it may not be possible to do ).

[Line 274 on Trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-admin/edit.php#L268) is where it looks like the actual title gets set. Is is possible / is there a way to filter into it and add my post type description?

Comment: No time to write a proper A, use this filter https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/views_this-screen-id/ to echo what you need, than return input unchanged

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The filter [`views_{$this->screen->id}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/views_this-screen-id/) is fired just after the title of post edit screen has been print to screen, so it's a safe place to just echo what you want.

So you can simply do:

```
function post_type_desc( $views ){

    $screen = get_current_screen();
    $post_type = get_post_type_object($screen->post_type);

    if ($post_type->description) {
      printf('<h4>%s</h4>', esc_html($post_type->description)); // echo 
    }

    return $views; // return original input unchanged
}

add_filter("views_edit-POST_TYPE_HERE", 'post_type_desc');
```