# Custom post listing page layout of custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

[image]

What is the best way to customise the standard wordpress custom post listing layout. To be specific, I am trying to add a subheading just below the **Lessons / Create New Lesson** button but before **All (0) | Trash (1)**

Is this possible with just a wordpress plugin or i have to modify core file OR maybe create a theme.

If it's possible, how much of this page is customizable by a plugin.

I would prefer a plugin solution.

Comment: Looking at `wp-admin/edit.php`, there's no action or filter called between the title and the post status selector. Thus, you would be best off using jQuery.

Comment: Try taking a look at [this answer by gmazzap](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/172033/7355)

Comment: Thanks for this, works like a charm, is there such a filter for post-new.php of a custom post